# android google map ~10k markers

Tags: android, google-maps, opengl-es-2.0

i am doing an android app, that is displaying markers on google map. The problem here is i need to handle ~10k markers. I can't do clustering as every marker is important and i can't show this markers from some zoom level as it is important to get the 'bigger picture'

WHAT I'VE TRIED:

- displaying only visible markers, but they are too dense and still I am left with few thousands and map just can't handle it..
- I moved away from google markers and created surfaceview over map fragment. And this works fine when I update my 'markers' after google map camera changes (after u stop dragging it), but this looks bad, because in between updates they are anchored to its position on screen not on map. And when i try to update my surfaceview while dragging it is not doing too well and freezes.

QUESTIONS:

- will moving from surfaceview to opengl improve rendering time?
- any other ideas?

EDIT:

firstly i will clarify, important is not every single marker, but the shape of the cloud of markers.
And also I've already tried heatmaps from google maps extension, but it kept freezing while dragging the map, heap kept growing until it finally breaks.

Comment: If the shape of the markers is what matters, you should be able to select only edge markers and create a single polyline around the edges of the cloud and draw that instead?

Comment: @cYrixmorten thanks for your answer, but it wouldn't be so straight forward. It would also require some nice grouping algorithm. And also I was already looking into this, but couldn't find solution how to fill polygons with gradient or how to color polyline nodes

Comment: Well, I cannot say what to do, as I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I think it might be worth looking into. As far as the algorithm goes, it should do picking an efficient sorting algorithm and make two lists, one sorted by latitude and the other by longitude. This should reveal the relevant points at the border of the two lists.

Comment: @cYrixmorten what i am tring to achive is the same I did here: [link](http://ibcol-meteo.pl/blitz2/) but the API that i am using right now is focused on poland only. (right now it's not stormy so there is not so many markers.

Comment: Oh I see.. Then I think I would try to figure out the problem when using heatmaps and try and correct the source code (as I recall it is open source right?). It also supports some other form of grouping doesnt it?  Would make sense to do clustering or the like I guess. In all cases, a preprocessing is a must as adding all markers will cause problems (as you also point out).

Comment: Maybe something like https://github.com/TeamWanari/HugeMapMaker

Answer (score 0):

Rendering markers in google map is very resource expensive task. If the marker is custom designed it will take more time to just to create the bitmap.Traditional way of creating marker will not help here, bcz rendering is done by Main Thread. You have to implement some parallel processing to create the markers, So redering markers will not disturb your main thread. You can implement something like this

http://leaks.wanari.com/2016/05/05/rendering-markers-for-android/

I hope it will help you. Good Luck.